# No rows in the junction table is referencing any rows in the table it connects

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, database

Here's the scenario, there are 3 tables:

- table1
- table2
- table1_to_table2 - junction table linking table1 and table2

When a row is deleted in table1, all references of that row must also be deleted in the junction table. It is possible that after some time there are no more rows in the junction table referencing any rows in table2.

You can define in the junction table , ON DELETE CASCADE, so that when there are records deleted in table1, rows referencing it in junction table would also get deleted. And you can be implement manually in your application to cleanup table2 every delete. But, is there a way to define the schema in mysql, so that automatically it ensures that when this happens, the rows in table2 will be cleaned up?

Comment: more cascading deletes

Comment: Question: are there records in `table2` that might not be related to any record in `table1`?

Comment: @limey, can you elaborate? :) note that relationship here is many to many, so i can't simply delete the row in table2 when it gets deleted in junction table

Comment: @MarianoD'Ascanio yes, i think that's possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way of doing this. You are going to have to perform a check On Delete of a row in the Table1_to_table2 table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this via schema definition.

You can protect that rule by coding it inside an Stored Procedure bound to `DELETE` on table1.